# Firestore Query failing to get documents when condition added

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to get a documents from firestore with a query to only get those with a certain field value. When I add the filter, which from everything I've looked at should work, it returns nothing.

Here is the code:

```
ArrayList<Service> services = new ArrayList<>();

db.collection("users/" + user.getUid() + "/" + Constants.SERVICES_TABLE)
         //customerID is a String field in this method block
        .whereEqualTo("customerID", customerID)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                    //this code is not reached because QueryDocumentSnapshot always has a length of 0

                    Service service = new Service(
                            document.get("date").toString(),
                            document.get("service").toString(),
                            document.get("notes").toString(),
                            document.get("customerID").toString(),
                            document.get("cost").toString(),
                            document.get("tips").toString());

                    services.add(service);

                }

                myCallback.onCallback(services);

            } else {
                Log.d("tag", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        });
```

When I remove the query filter I get all Service objects as expected, but with the filter nothing is received.

[image]

Comment: Did you tried instead with directly using `task` to do like in the docs of firebase and create a `new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>()`?

Comment: I have, but the result is the same. The documents all get returned without a statement, but not with one.

Comment: And you sure that your customID is the correct one? Did you debugged it in your IDE ?

Comment: I debbuged it and everything matches up as it should. I also copied the value off firestore and used a notebad app to compare it with the value shown by debugger.

Comment: Did you checked if task is successful or any exception or error printed in logcat?

Comment: Does this line of code `Log.d("tag", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());` print out something? Have you tried to use your code with hardcoded values? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo task.isSuccessful is true

Comment: @AndrewHeschl Have you tried to use your code with hardcoded values?

Comment: @AlexMamo I've tried hard coding every variable dependant part

Comment: @AndrewHeschl And what was the result?

Comment: @AlexMano same result... but I just figured out my issue. Somehow a space ended up before the customerID field. I didn't catch it because double tapping the field in firestore will not highlight the space and the debugger trimmed it. This one's my error. Thanks for your help.